# Conformal mapping of part of an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, conformal-geometry

I have a question about conformal mapping. I am wanting to map annuli to some other simple domain (probably rectangular). I have an image of my problem below

[image: My drawing]

In image A. we see a standard annulus which has been cut radially. We can easily map this annulus to a rectangle using the transformation log(z).

However, if I cut the annulus horizontally, as in image B. then this transformation no longer maps to a "nice" domain.

Questions:

Is there a name for chopped annuli as in A. and B.?

Is there any nice conformal transformation for B.?

Thanks v much!

Comment: I would unfortunately be quite surprised if there was a nice comformal map between $B$ and the unit disc. I checked a few books of conformal transformations and I've got nothing that remotely applies to it.

Comment: Ah, thanks for checking for me. This was my attempt to solve the Laplace equation on B. Back to square 1!